# why the method for adding node in a doubly linked list is different from singly linked list in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

here is a cpp program for creating a singly linked list :

```
#include <iostream> 


`using namespace std ;


  //  starting with linked list 


   class node {

   public : 
   int data ; 
    node * next ; 


    // constructer 
    node ( int value){
    data = value ;  
    next = NULL ; 
      }
     };


    int insertathead( node *&head , int data  ){

       node*newhead ;
       newhead = new node(data) ;  
   newhead -> next = head ; 
   head = newhead ; 

    } 


   void print(node*& head)
 {
   node* temp = head;

  while (temp != NULL) {
    cout << temp->data << " -> ";
    temp = temp->next;
 }
 cout << "NULL" << endl;
    }

   int main () {  
 
 node* node1 = NULL  ; 
 insertathead(node1, 5 )  ;  
  insertathead( node1 , 10) ;  
 insertathead(node1 , 15 ) ;
 insertathead( node1 , 20 ) ;
  insertathead( node1 , 30 ) ; 
      print ( node1 ) ;


    return 0 ; 
      }
```

> here is another cpp program for creating a doubly linked list :

```
           #include <iostream> 
           using namespace std  ; 
            class node {
             public : 

          int data; 
    node*next ; 
    node* prev ; 
       // constructor 
    node( int data )
      {
         this -> data = data ; 
         next = NULL ; 
         prev = NULL ; 
     }

     } ; 

     void insertathead ( node*&head , int d  ) {
       if ( head == NULL ) {
          node*temp = new node(d) ; 
           head = temp ; 
            }
          else 
         {node*temp = new node(d) ; 
             temp -> next = head ; 
           head  -> prev = temp ; 
             head  = temp ;} 
                }

       void print ( node**head ){
       node*temp = *head ; 
        while ( temp != NULL )
         {
           cout << temp -> data << " ->  " ; 
 
         temp = temp -> next ; 
     }
       cout << "NULL " ; 
    }
      int main () { 
     node* head = NULL ; 
      insertathead( head , 5 ) ;
       insertathead( head , 10) ;  
      insertathead( head , 15 ) ;
       insertathead(head , 20 ) ;
       insertathead(head , 30 ) ; 

       print ( &head ) ;

  return 0 ; 

    }
```

**now in the function inserathead in the singly linked list i do not have to creat a
special reason like if( head = NULL ) in doubly linked list but in dubly linked list the
program wont print the list without using such case , why is that ?**

Comment: What do you think happens when you access `head->prev` _when there is no head_?

Comment: "why the method for adding node in a doubly linked list is different from singly linked list in c++?" - Because a singly linked list is not a doubly linked list..? Different data structure, different handling...

Answer (score 0):

Because in one case head is never dereferenced so it doesn't matter if it is `nullptr` or not. In the double linked case though you have:

```
head  -> prev = temp ;
```